# Javascript - Calculating total price function and need to throw zero at the end if only 3 numbers

Tags: javascript, function, price

The function I’m using calculates the total by dividing by 100 which is only a problem when the price equals something like “27.5” so I want to add a zero at the end if that’s the case. Would I use an if statement? If so, how might I go about writing it?

```
var frm = document.forms.myForm;
frm.onchange = function(e) {
    var tot = 0;
    for( var i = 0, l = frm.elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        if( frm.elements[i].checked ) {
            tot += parseFloat( frm.elements[i].getAttribute('data-price') );
        }  
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = "$" + ( tot / 100 );
}
```

[calculate total price function on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZpnD/)

Answer (score 1):

Per http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/formatnumber.shtml use .toFixed(2) to maintain it as 2 decimals.  Include it in an if statement to only apply to those non-integer answers.

Can check for integers with something like:

```
function isInt(value) {
  return !isNaN(value) && 
     parseInt(Number(value)) == value && 
     !isNaN(parseInt(value, 10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var profits=2489.8237
profits.toFixed(3) => returns 2489.824 (round up)
profits.toFixed(2) => returns 2489.82
profits.toFixed(7) => returns 2489.8237000 (padding)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this

```
var frm = document.forms.myForm;
frm.onchange = function(e) {
    var tot = 0;
    for( var i = 0, l = frm.elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        if( frm.elements[i].checked ) {
            tot += parseFloat( frm.elements[i].getAttribute('data-price') );
        }  
    }
    tot /= 100
    var numDigits = String(tot).split('').filter(function(char) {
        return /\d/.test(char)
    }).length;
    if (numDigits === 3) {
        tot += "0";
    });
    document.getElementById('total').value = "$" + tot;
}
```

1. `tot` is a number. You need to perform type conversion to convert it to a string. You can then separate all the characters into separate array elements with the `split` function
2. Now that we have an array, we can select only the numbers by running the `filter` function and using the `test` method to test for a regular expression.
3. We then call the `length` method on the array to find the length of the number of characters that match that expression.
4. We now use a conditional expression for finding if the number of digits is exactly equal to 3. If it is, we append 0 to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var frm = document.forms.myForm;
frm.onchange = function(e) {
    var tot = 0;
    for( var i = 0, l = frm.elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        if( frm.elements[i].checked ) {
            tot += parseFloat( frm.elements[i].getAttribute('data-price') );
        }  
    }
    tot = tot/100 == Math.round(tot/100) ? tot/100 : (tot/100).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Key Stage 1</th>
            <th>Buy on Paper</th>
            <th>Buy on CD</th>
            <th>Buy on both</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Year 1 All Blocks & Units (15 assessments in total)</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="0" data-price="2500" />
                £25</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="1" data-price="2500" />
                £25 †</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="2" data-price="4000" />
                £40</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Year 2 All Blocks & Units (15 assessments in total)</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="3" data-price="2500" />
                £25</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="4" data-price="2500" />
                £25 †</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="5" data-price="4000" />
                £40</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Give me it all and save some monehhhh!</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="6" data-price="4750" />
                £47.50</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="7" data-price="4750" />
                £47.50 †</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage1" value="8" data-price="7500" />
                £75</label>
            </td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
                
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Key Stage 2</th>
            <th>Buy on Paper</th>
            <th>Buy on CD</th>
            <th>Buy on both</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Year 1 All Blocks & Units (15 assessments in total)</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="0" data-price="2500" />
                £25</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="1" data-price="2500" />
                £25 †</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="2" data-price="4000" />
                £40</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Year 2 All Blocks & Units (15 assessments in total)</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="3" data-price="2500" />
                £25</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="4" data-price="2500" />
                £25 †</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="5" data-price="4000" />
                £40</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Give me it all and save some monehhhh!</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="6" data-price="4750" />
                £47.50</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="7" data-price="4750" />
                £47.50 †</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="keystage2" value="8" data-price="7500" />
                £75</label>
            </td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="total" />
```